# How to Set States Inside Loop React Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a functions that should update data provided by the user. But due to some strange reason its only updating first value of `quizzes`. Its not updating `Topic` value and when adding second value to `quizzes` it revert backs to 1st value.

**Data**

```
[
  {
    "Topic": [ "Biology", "Introduction to Biology" ],
    "Question": "Example of micro molecule is:",
    "Quizzes" : ["2022 Biology Geek", "General Knowledge"]
  },
  {
    "Question": "Pepsin enzyme works in;"
  }
]
```

**Code**

```
const [finalData, setFinalData] = useState({
    TOPIC: [],
    QUIZZES: []
})
const setData = () => {
    const ei = userSelectedData.topic;
    const yr = userSelectedData.quiz

    selectedDocsID.forEach(doc => {
      fetchDoc("ques", doc)
      .then((response) => {
        const TField = response["Topic"]
        const QField = response["Quizzes"]
        
        const newTs = new Set([...finalData.TOPIC]);
        const newQs = new Set([...finalData.QUIZZES]);

        //If Topic Field Does not Exist
        if (TField == undefined) {
          newTs.add(doc);
          setFinalData({ ...finalData, EI: Array.from(newTs) })
        }
        //If Topic Field Exist But Don't have Requried Value
        else if (TField.includes(ei) != true) {
          newTs.add(doc);
          setFinalData({ ...finalData, EI: Array.from(newTs) })
        }
        //If Quiz Field Does not Exist
        if (QField == undefined) {
          newQs.add(doc);
          setFinalData({ ...finalData, YR: Array.from(newQs) })
        }
        //If Quiz Field Exist But Don't have Requried Value
        else if (QField.includes(yr) != true) {
          newQs.add(doc);
          setFinalData({ ...finalData, YR: Array.from(newQs) })
        }
      })
    });
  }
<Button onClick={() => setData()}>Update Data</Button>
```

**Current Result**

```
//Displaying Results by console.log inside useEffects Hook
{
    "TOPIC": [],
    "QUIZZES": [
        "2022 Biology Geek",
        "General Knowledge"
    ]
}
//After Few Seconds
{
    "TOPIC": [],
    "QUIZZES": [
        "2022 Biology Geek"
    ]
}
```

**Expected Result**

```
{
    "TOPIC": ["Biology"],
    "QUIZZES": [
        "2022 Biology Geek",
        "General Knowledge"
    ]
}
```

Comment: You are calling fetch in a loop and set state in every call, what would you expect?

Comment: I'm using an Set to append values at the end

Comment: JavaScript's objects don't have an end or a beggining. You are overriding the same values every time.

Comment: So what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Either moving `setFinalData` outside of the for loop or using an array to handle each id. I'm not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: I'm checking If (Topic and Quizzes Fields) Exists or Not. If they exist check if they contain user Provided Data. If they don't have that data `setFinalData ` so I can update data base